# android TabLayout changing color of selected tab icon showing dim white color

Tags: android, android-tablayout, porter-duff

I have used tab layout with image of android design library. When changing color of selected tab icon white,white color is not showing perfectly but it shows dim white color. How to show prefect white color on selected tab?

```
slidingTabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab_recent);
slidingTabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab_profile);
slidingTabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab_contacts);
slidingTabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab_settings);

slidingTabLayout.getTabAt(0).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
slidingTabLayout.getTabAt(1).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#a8a8a8"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
slidingTabLayout.getTabAt(2).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#a8a8a8"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
slidingTabLayout.getTabAt(3).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#a8a8a8"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);


slidingTabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#a8a8a8"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried #FFFFFF instead of Color.WHITE ?

Comment: @Le_Master i have used , it shows same color as Color.WHITE

Comment: i am also doing same but its not working @RajeshKhadka

Comment: what is the color of drawable? @Erum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked by changing all colors(Color.WHITE,Color.BLUE) and drawable.It didn't worked for me. Later on , I checked the  drawable used it was of color brown .After changing color of drawable white it worked for me.

It was drawing in the brown drawable due to PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN. For more information about [PorterDuff.Mode](http://ssp.impulsetrain.com/porterduff.html)

Comment: Hero. PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN was the trick for icons black by default.